# Planing to switch from Windows

Tags: drivers, upgrade, windows

I want to switch from Windows & my use with PC is music movies picture editing (creating hdr, etc) and torrent download so I need security and performance.

I'm currently using Windows 7 64bit
hardware:
intel i7 4770 3.4ghz
8gb ram
nvidia geforce gtx 650ti boost 2gb
and standard performance HDD

When I'm upgrading which are all the drivers, that I will need and which are the drivers available by default?

My net is always on and torrent is always on download :P so I hope I get security.

Answer (score 2):

For the usage you make of your PC, Ubuntu is a very good choice. Considering your hardware, it should run very fast.

For the drivers, once Ubuntu is installed, you will receive a notification. The only thing you will have to do is to activate the driver, Ubuntu will take care of download and install it.

For torrent download, the software that handle them is Transmission, and it comes with Ubuntu.

For security, it is very safe.